# MobaXterm The fist character of bash prompt is showing up on a different line, how do I fix this?

Tags: bash, prompt, xterm

When I type in a command in MobaXterm, the first character of my prompt shows up at the end of the next line, and the rest of the prompt is on the line after. It doesn't seem to affect anything performance-wise, but I can't seem to find anyone else with this issue. If anyone has any ideas as to what might be causing this, some help would be much appreciated.

[screenshot of my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7oR8.png)

Answer (score 2):

On a MobaXterm window, Click on Settings->Configuration and then in the Terminal tab un-select Display separation line.

[Click here for a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLE2K.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is not due to a setting in MobaXterm, but rather it is due to the default prompt set in the version of bash cygwin installed by MobaXterm, which adds a newline.

You can change the prompt by setting PS1 in ~/.bash_profile (or if you set it up ~/.bashrc). For example I add this line and now there is no newline at the prompt:

PS1="\h [\e[33m]\w[\e[0m]> "

Comment: As mentioned by @Emilio, you probably also want to uncheck the setting "Display separation line." in the MobaXterm settings.